# WPF MVVM c# binding textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a View in it : listview with grid columns one of the columns is a textBox.
I need to some how be able to binding it From the ViewModel.
is there a way to do it ?

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView x:Name="activeContents" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
         <GridViewColumn Width="30" Header=" ">
             <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <Image Source="{Binding IconFileFullPath}" Width="16" Height="16" ></Image>
                  </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn Width="150"  Header="Content" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="125"  Header="Content Category"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding contentCategory}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="125"  Header="Content Version" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding version}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="85"  Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding status}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Priority ">
         <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <TextBox Text="{Binding seq, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="67" />
              </DataTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

tried to binding but no effect .
read something about working with behavior but don't know how to do that. is there an easy way ?

more code :

```
<!-- Active Contents-->
                            <ListView x:Name="ContentsList" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=contentToAction}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = activeContents, Mode= TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,6,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF454545"
                                       SelectionMode="Single" Height="130" Width="650" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                                       dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" dd:DragDrop.UseDefaultDragAdorner="True">
                                <ListView.Resources>
                                    <ContextMenu x:Key="ItemContextMenu">
                                        <MenuItem Header="Open in CM" Command="{Binding DataContext.OpenContentVersionInCm,   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Execute" Command="{Binding DataContext.ContentCopyCommand,   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                                        <MenuItem Header="Update Execution Priority"  Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateExecutionPriorityCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                    <Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
                                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListView.Resources>



                                <ListView.View>
                                    <GridView x:Name="activeContents" AllowsColumnReorder="False">

                                        <GridViewColumn Width="30" Header=" ">
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding IconFileFullPath}" Width="16" Height="16" ></Image>
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="150"  Header="Content" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"/>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="125"  Header="Content Category"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding contentCategory}"/>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="125"  Header="Content Version" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding version}"/>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="85"  Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding status}"/>
                                        <GridViewColumn Width="90" Header="Priority ">
                                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding seq, Mode=TwoWay}"  Width="67" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        </GridViewColumn>
                                    </GridView>
                                </ListView.View>

                                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Are you binding an ObservableColelction, or any collection, to your ListView?

Comment: yes, its an ObservableColelction

Comment: post your relevant viewmodel code and your itemssource binding. and check your output window for binding exceptions. btw BradleyDotnet posted the right answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Once you are inside the `GridViewColumn` your DataContext changes to the bound object.

That means, if it has a property `seq`; your binding will work correctly. If you wanted the property `seq` on the view model itself however, you have two options. Either way, your path becomes:

```
"{Binding Path=DataContext.seq}"
```

The first is to name your window "root" and do an `ElementName` binding:

```
"{Binding Path=DataContext.seq, ElementName=root}"
```

The other is to use a `RelativeSource` binding:

```
"{Binding Path=DataContext.seq, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"
```

Comment: i changed <TextBox Text="{Binding seq, Mode=TwoWay}" />
 to <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.seq, ElementName=root}" /> but with no effect

Comment: @igor Are you getting any `System.Data` errors in your output window? They will point to any typos in your binding. Also make sure to name the root element if you use `ElementName`.

Comment: no errors , 
when it like this <TextBox Text="{Binding seq, Mode=TwoWay}" /> i can bind it from the model.
"{Binding Path=DataContext.seq}" like this not from the model and not from the viewModel

Comment: @igor If it isn't working; you should see *some* error. Regardless, if it was working before; why did you ask the question?

Comment: i can bind it only from Model , i need the binding from the ViewModel

Comment: @igor You should *never* be binding to the model. Regardless, you need to include the model/view model code that isn't working; and any System.Data exceptions you are seeing. I can't see enough of your program to tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I don't want to bind from the model only said that i can, but can't from the view model. 
added more coded , thanks

Comment: so this video , seems like it's what I need .
but it didn't worked to :( 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIr8nL3OgwA

Comment: @igor But *why* can't you bind from the view model? Is it set as your data context? I still don't have enough info to tell you what is wrong.